# How can I ignore the exception in Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, web-crawler

I use **Python Selenium** for scraping a website, 
but my crawler stopped because of a exception:

> `StaleElementReferenceException`: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

How can i continue to crawl even if the element is not attached?

**UPDATE**

i change my code to:

```
try:
    libelle1 = prod.find_element_by_css_selector('.em11')
    libelle1produit = libelle1.text  # libelle1 OK
    libelle1produit = libelle1produit.decode('utf-8', 'strict')
except StaleElementReferenceException:
    pass
```

but i have this exception

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element
```

i also tried this one:

```
try:
    libelle1 = prod.find_element_by_css_selector('.em11')
    libelle1produit = libelle1.text  # libelle1 OK
    libelle1produit = libelle1produit.decode('utf-8', 'strict')
except :
    pass
```

Comment: consider posting some more of the code that caused the problem. Otherwise, the next best thing to offer is simply to ignore the exception with try-except or `with supress` context manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the browser rendering engine or Javascript engine is using the element and it is blocking other external operations on this element. You can attempt to access it after some time. If it is not accessible for longer duration, an exception can be thrown. Some good examples are given [here](http://darrellgrainger.blogspot.in/2012/06/staleelementexception.html).

Answer (score 5):

Put a try-except block around the piece of code that produced that error.

Answer (score 5):

To be more specific about what John Gordon is talking about. Handle the [`StaleElementReferenceException`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException) common selenium exception and ignore it:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException

try:
    element.click()
except StaleElementReferenceException:  # ignore this error
    pass  # TODO: consider logging the exception
```